# SSL code inside Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ssl

I'm looking for the code inside Hibernate that manages SSL connections and certificates -- however, so far I have been unable to. The repository I've been looking at is here, https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is a object relational mapping library -- it maps java object manipulation into SQL transactions. You don't use it to manage SSL connections / certificate (although it might / not contain code that does this). So yes maybe you're missing (a lot of) things.

Typically you need to configure DBMS datasource for hibernate to use, and if you need SSL for your database connection this is where you configure it

Datasource is typically vendor specific, plus you have to take into account connection pooling provider